# Function argument's default value equal to another argument

Tags: python, function, arguments, default

Is it possible to define a function argument's default value to another argument in the same function definition? Something like:

```
def func(a, b=a):
  print a, b
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: Why not assign `a` to `b` in the first line of the function?

Comment: You can't do that, you need to do `b=None` then `if b is None: b = a`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4575326/3001761 (which you could have found trivially if you'd searched for this...)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No. This is not possible. The Python interpreter thinks that you want to assign the default value of argument `b` to a global variable `a` when there isn't a global variable `a`.

You might want to try something like this:

```
def func(a, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b = a
```

Comment: this wouldn't allow passing only one variable

Comment: @EthanBierlein *"the best response a good SO contributor can make is to search for duplicates"* - i.e. rather than answering.