# String concatenation inside function arguments

Tags: python, string, function, xlsxwriter

Why the code below throws undefined name sheetname?

```
def PlotChart(charttype = 'line', sheetname = 'CA', values = '='+sheetname+'!$M$1:$M$400'):
```

Any ways I can fix this?

Comment: Define `sheetname`.

Comment: sheetname = 'CA' is that not?

Comment: No that will not work. I think you should define what you want to send to `value` correct data before calling `PlotChart`

Comment: I really think giving more information on the expected output would really helps us help you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575326/in-python-can-i-specify-a-function-arguments-default-in-terms-of-other-argumen

Answer (score 4):

Default parameter values are evaluated when the function is *defined*, thus you can not access another parameter value that will only be known when the function is *called*.

I'd suggest using `None` as the default and then setting the proper default value afterwards.

```
def PlotChart(charttype='line', sheetname='CA', values=None):
    if values is None:
        values = '=' + sheetname + '!$M$1:$M$400'
    ...
```

Or slightly shorter, using `or` to get a "default" value (this will also replace empty `""`, though)

```
    values = values or ('=' + sheetname + '!$M$1:$M$400')
```

If `sheetname` always has to be part of `values`, you could also expect a format string, and then format it with the actual value for `sheetname` after the function has been called:

```
def PlotChart(charttype='line', sheetname='CA', values='={}!$M$1:$M$400'):
    values = values.format(sheetname)
    ...
```

Comment: The last one is very fragile; it will break if the caller provides an incompatible format string. I don't seen any reason *not* to use the first suggestion that explicitly checks for a `None` value.

Comment: @chepner Yes, it's fragile, and the format should probably be explained in the docstring. One benefit might be that the default is more obvious than when using `None` and checking it somewhere (preferrably in the first line) in the code. (On the other hand, when using `None` one could also explain the _actual_ default in the docstring.)

Answer (score 1):

**If there will always be sheetname in values**

You should perform the addition inside the function:

```
def PlotChart(charttype = 'line', sheetname = 'CA', values = '!$M$1:$M$400'):
    values = '=' + sheetname + values
```

**If you want user to change completely values:**

You should call the function with what you want

```
def PlotChart(values, charttype = 'line', sheetname = 'CA'):
    ...

PlotChart(charttype = 'line', sheetname = 'CA', values = '=' + sheetname + values)
```

**If you want both:**

tobias_k answers is the best: use None

```
def PlotChart(charttype='line', sheetname='CA', values=None):
    if values is None:
        values = '='+sheetname+'!$M$1:$M$400'):
    ...
```

Comment: What if user wants to use a different value for `values`?

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: You could also make this a bit more generic by expecting a format string for values: `values='={}!$M$1:$M$400'`