# Passing expression value to be computed at run-time as default argument in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, palindrome

I want to make the typical implementation of palindrome function without having to specify the length of the string and its `a` and `b` as follows

```
def palindrome(s,a=0,b=len(s)-1):
    if a>=b:
        return True
    return s[a] == s[b] and palindrome(s,a=a+1,b=b-1)
```

so the user just invoke the function like that `palindrome("abcba")` and the `b` value gets computed in the first invokation of the recursion to get the value `len(s)-1`

Comment: [*The other argument names don't exist until the function is actually entered.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4575347/5858851) You can do something like default `b` to `None` and then inside the function do `if b is None: b=len(s) - 1`

Comment: I know this trick, I just want to see if run-time evaluation for arguments is possible

Comment: @OmarKhalid Yes, it can be done. What you need to do is define the *whole function* at run-time. This can be achieved by putting it inside a wrapper function, which then calls it internally and returns its result.

Comment: I know that too, I just wanted to see that If it could happen as I wanted excatly. But, apparently It can't happen. Thank you all

Comment: @OmarKhalid It is always advisable to explain what you're already considered, so as to avoid your question being closed as a duplicate.